# Only get the last pair of dictionary in python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a script that read and parse a file that has lines as follows, every field is separated by ",":

`Ezequiel Garay,23,230,0,1`

I made a function to obtain the first field that has the maximum value resulting of: (4th_field * 3rd_field ) / 2nd_field

My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def maxperf(lj):
    n = lj[0]
    if (int(lj[1])) > 0:
            performance=((int(lj[3]) + 1)*(int(lj[2])))/int(lj[1]) 
    else: performance=0

    par = dict([(n,performance)])    
    return max(par, key = par.get)

archivojugs = open("datos_ej1.txt")
jugadores = []
for jugador in archivojugs:
    jugadores = jugador.split(",")
    mp=maxperf(jugadores) 


print(mp)
archivojugs.close()
```

The problem is that I get only the last pair of the dictionary (I mean, it's as if each line overwrite the earlier one instead of append it), what's wrong with my code?

**UPDATE:**
I've modified the answers:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def calcperf(n,pj,d,gg):
    '''Calculo performance'''
    if int(pj) > 0:
        p = ((int(gg) + 1 ) * int(d)) / int(pj)
    else: p = 0

    return  p

def maxperf(lp):
    '''Saco el jugador con mejor rendimiento'''
    mp = max(lp, key=lp.get)
    return mp



archivojugs = open("datos_ej1.txt")
listperfs = {}

for jugador in archivojugs.readlines():
    NOMBRE, PJ, DISTANCIA, GOLES, CONTROL = jugador.split(',')
    rendimiento = calcperf(NOMBRE,PJ,DISTANCIA,GOLES)
    listperfs[NOMBRE] = rendimiento

mejorperf = maxperf(listperfs)

print(mejorperf)

archivojugs.close
```

And it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're printing `mp`, which changes in each iteration of your for loop and you only get its state from the last iteration. Also, your `par` dictionary is local to `maxperf` function and contains only one entry each time you call that function.

You need need a non-local dictionary which would store results of your `maxperf` function. Let's create one which doesn't store computed performance at all, just returns it:

```
def perf(lj):
    n = lj[0]
    if (int(lj[1])) > 0:
        performance=((int(lj[3]) + 1)*(int(lj[2])))/int(lj[1]) 
    else:
        performance=0
    return n, performance
```

Now, back to our loop:

```
par = {}
for jugador in archivojugs:
    jugadores = jugador.split(",")
    name, p = perf(jugadores)
    par[name] = p

maxperf = max(par, key=par.get)
print(maxperf)
```

Also, keep in mind that storing performances in dictionary, just for sake of
finding maximum value, is unnecessary and you'd be better with something like this:

```
import operator
mp = max(perf(jugador.split(',')) for jugador in archivojugs,
         key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print(mp)
```

Comment: I don't understand how does the line `name, perf = perf(jugadores)` work

Comment: Oh, I see it gets what the perf function return

Comment: @sebelk: it unpacks tuple returned by `perf()` into two variables: `name` and `perf`.

Comment: I've applied your fixes, but I get: `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`.

Comment: @sebelk Poor naming, shame on me. rename `perf` variable or `perf` function to something else so their names won't clash. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Is there a way that function returns directly the key corresponding to the maximum value?

Comment: @sebelk: sure, if you pass `par` dictionary to it, you can search it. But you need a persistent dictionary outside of this function - you can't create it from scratch everytime the your function is called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130300/discussion-between-sebelk-and-michal-goral).